# Pass value to Jquery function

Tags: jquery

I would like to pass value of index to function like this. Who can give me some ideas!

```
index = 3;
$("#addNewRow"+index+"").on("click", function () {


});
```

Comment: what is index in you html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass it, you can directly use it:

```js
index = 3;
$("#addNewRow"+index).on("click", function () {
  alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addNewRow3">Add New Row</button>
```

That's the easiest and best way, but you can do it in many other ways. For example, you can extract it back from the object ID:

```js
index = 3;
$("#addNewRow"+index).on("click", function () {
  alert(this.id.substring(9));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addNewRow3">Add New Row</button>
```

Or you can pass it using event data:

```js
index = 3;
$("#addNewRow"+index).on("click", index, function (e) {
  alert(e.data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addNewRow3">Add New Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use:

```
$("#addNewRow"+index).on("click", function () {
..
..
});
```